# during HBase scan with MapReduce, the number of Reducer is always one

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I do HBase scan in Mapper, then Reducer writes result to HDFS.
The number of records output by mapper is roughly 1,000,000,000.

The problem is the number of reducers is always one, though I have set `-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=100`. The reduce process is very slow.

// edit at 2016-12-04 by 祝方泽
the code of my main class:

```
public class GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbase extends Configured implements Tool {

public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = new Job(conf, conf.get("mapred.job.name"));
    String input_table = conf.get("input.table");       

    job.setJarByClass(GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbase.class);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(500);
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("info"), Bytes.toBytes("sitemap_type"));
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("info"), Bytes.toBytes("is_send_to_spider"));

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
            input_table, 
            scan, 
            GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbaseMapper.class, 
            Text.class, 
            Text.class, 
            job);

    /*job.setMapperClass(GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbaseMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);*/

    job.setReducerClass(GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbaseReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    if (job.waitForCompletion(true) && job.isSuccessful()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbase(), args);
    System.exit(res);
}

}
```

here is the script to run this MapReduce job:

```
table="xxx"
output="yyy"
sitemap_type="zzz"

JOBCONF=""
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapred.job.name=test_for_scan_hbase"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dinput.table=$table"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapred.output.dir=$output"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Ddemand.sitemap.type=$sitemap_type"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts='-Xmx8192m'"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=9216"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts='-Xmx1536m'"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapreduce.reduce.java.opts='-Xmx1536m'"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=100"
JOBCONF="${JOBCONF} -Dmapred.job.priority=VERY_HIGH"

hadoop fs -rmr $output
hadoop jar get_url_not_sent_2_spider_from_hbase_hourly.jar hourly.GetUrlNotSent2SpiderFromHbase $JOBCONF
echo "===== scan HBase finished ====="
```

I set `job.setNumReduceTasks(100);` in code, it worked.

Comment: pls check my answer below. Hope that helps!

Comment: also do `echo $JOBCONF` to cross check the properties you applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned only one reduce is working that's the obvious reason why reducer is very slow.

#### Unified way to know configuration properties applied to Job (this you call for every job you execute to know parameters are passed correctly) :

add the below method to your job driver mentioned above to print configuration entries applied from all possible sources i.e either from -D or some where else please add this method call in driver program before your job is submitted :

```
public static void printConfigApplied(Configuration conf) 
     try {
                conf.writeXml(System.out);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

This proves your system properties are not applied from the command line i.e -Dxxx so the way you are passing system properties is not correct. since pro grammatically.

Since job.setnumreducetasks is working , **I strongly suspect the below where your system properties are not passed correctly to driver.**

```
 Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = new Job(conf, conf.get("mapred.job.name"));
```

change this to the example in [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html)

Comment: thank you. I used `-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=100`, and there is no `job.setNumReduceTasks` called in my code. But there is only 1 reducer. I can't figure it out.

Comment: I add the code, may be it will be helpful for you and others to find the problem.

Comment: I dont see your code is faulty. can you try this property `mapreduce.job.reduces=X` I think its taking default value that is 1

Comment: Hi please follow the method to print all the properties applied. some your system properties are leaked...

Comment: I used `printConfigApplied()` function, it print hundreds of properties, but I do not find `reduce.tasks` property.

Comment: I guess the problem is related to `HBaseConfiguration`

Comment: ya it will print that's very good method for debugging any mismatches in properties... your property not found,  so that means your config options not passed to driver program and when you apply programatically its applied so need to to change the way you are passing config to job. that will solve the issue.